Python Regex to match the FIRST repetition of a digit
Examples:

For 0123123123, 1 should be matched since the 2nd 1 appears before the repetition of any other digit.
For 01234554321, 5 should be matched since the 2nd 5 appears before the repetition of any other digit.

Some regexes that I have tried:

The below works for the 1st but not the 2nd example. It matches 1 instead because 1 is the first digit that appears in the string which is subsequently repeated.

import re
m = re.search(r"(\d).*?\1", string)
print(m.group(1))


The below works for the 2nd but not the 1st example. It matches 3 instead - in particular the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of the digit. I do not know why it behaves that way.

import re
m = re.search(r"(\d)(?!(\d).*?\2).*?\1", string)
print(m.group(1))


Could the string contain anything other than digits?

Yes, the string could contain any character.

Is there a reason why regex is needed when a far simpler (and more efficient) technique as proposed by @blhsing is clearly superior?

There is no particular reason why regex is needed. When I first encountered the problem my immediate thought was that there would be a fast and simple regex solution - I did not expect it to be as complicated.

The question shouldn't assume regex is the best or only aprpach, I'd rename it "Match the FIRST repetition of a digit in a string of digits, by regex or otherwise".

If the string can contain any (non-whitespace) character (uppercase? punctuation?), then what should the right answer for "abdAbd0123123123" be? 'a'? 'd'? '1'? If the string can contain any character then why do you write your pattern to only look for '\d' instead of '\w' or '[a-zA-Z0-9...]'?

I am looking for the first repetition of a digit as mentioned in the title.

One idea: capture the end of the string and add it in the negative lookahead (group 2 here):
(\d)(?=.*?\1(.*))(?!.*?(\d).*?\3.+?\2$)

This way you can control where the subpattern .*?(\d).*?\3 in the negative lookahead ends. If .+?\2$ succeeds, that means there's an other digit that is repeated before the one in group 1.
I anchored the pattern for the regex101 demo with ^.*?, but you don't need to do that with the re.search method.

Other way: reverse the string and find the last repeated digit:
re.search(r'^.*(\d).*?\1', string[::-1]).group(1)


Great idea to work on the reversed string! I think you do not need to be lazy on the second .*? since the first one "pins you in the corner" already.

@DuesserBaest: exact, the second quantifier doesn't need to be lazy as it doesn't need to be greedy. You can choose the one you want.

Regex may not be the right tool for the task. While the regex in @CasimiretHippolyte's answer works, it is rather inefficient having to scan the entire rest of the string for each character in the string until a matching character is found, costing an average time complexity of O(n ^ 2).
A more efficient approach with a linear time complexity would be to use a set to keep track of characters that have been encountered, and return the first character already added to the set:
def first_repeating_digit(string):
    seen = set()
    for digit in filter(str.isdigit, string):
        if digit in seen:
            return digit
        seen.add(digit)
    raise ValueError('No repeating digit found.')

so that:
for s in '0123123123', '01234554321':
    print(s, first_repeating_digit(s))

outputs:
0123123123 1 
01234554321 5

Demo here
Benchmark test result:
blhsing 0123123123 1.2911038296297193
blhsing 01234554321 1.3835312821902335
CasimiretHippolyte 0123123123 3.6279739402234554
CasimiretHippolyte 01234554321 4.1985282939858735


If you could make use of the regex PyPi regex module, you might use a lookbehind assertion with an infinite quantifier and then use re.search to get the first match.
(\d)(?<=\1\d+)


(\d) Capture a single digit in group 1
(?<= Positive lookbehind, assert that from the current position to the left is

\1 Match the same digit as captured in group 1 using a backreference
\d+ Match 1 or more digits


) Close the lookbehing

See a regex demo and a Python demo.
